# Regarding Division of TextArea in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Hello EveryOne, 
           The Question I may be asking may be easyone.I'm a newbie to JavaFX and I've got work regarding this. So please help out. Here is my question ---
Can i divide entire TextArea into different parts - like Top Portion for Holding History/Log. Middle Part for using Styling(like ComboBoxes to set font and color accordingly) and Bottom part of that textarea to type messages. So that those msg are sent to Top part after clicking send button.

So, I was not able to figure out whether i can do it or not. If So, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SplitPane or similar container, and just have multiple text areas
[image]

The picture above is using a GridPane

Comment: Thanks. But i had a constraint. that i have to use BorderPane, ScrollPane HBox, VBox and nothing else

Comment: @chandrakishore   Yeah you can do the same thing Nevets is suggesting just use a VBox instead of a GridPane. Can you give a better description or an example of your expected result.

Comment: BorderPane, HBox, VBox all work the same. They can be partitioned, and controls can be added. 
I just used a GridPane in the example above.  You can pretend I said VBox, because it looks the same lol.

Comment: Add and some code so the OP will accept the answer maybe :)

Comment: I was going to add some code, but wasnt sure if they were a scenebuilder/fxml person, or preferred coding everything in the java file itself. You all could totally upvote it though, I wouldnt be mad at all!